# Solspace Tag: Not all tags from the tag group are listed

Tags: solspace, solspace-tag

I have tagged products with colors and to display list of those colors I'm using code below:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="products" category_group="1" category="not 7|8|9" status="retail|showroom|open" dynamic="no" orderby="title" sort="asc"}
{exp:tag:tags entry_id="{entry_id}" tag_group_name="Attributes" websafe_separator="-"}
{tag}
<?php $tags['{tag_id}'] = '{tag}'; ?>
<?php $web_tags['{tag}'] = '{websafe_tag}'; ?>
{/exp:tag:tags}
{/exp:channel:entries}

{!-- Sort tags by name ascending --}
<?php print_r($tags); ?>
```

and output looks like:

```
blue ivory lacquer wood wooden black brass chrome lacquer black brass chrome lacquer silver brass chrome white black brass lacquer black brass chrome lacquer black lacquer silver brass glass gold brown wooden black tan beige tan chrome mirror silver steel white black brown gold multicolor black silver black silver multicolor white black silver black gold black white black white black gold white black gold brass leather mahogany red wood wooden black and white acrylic acrylic black glass

Array ( [19] => blue [14] => ivory [137] => lacquer [129] => wood [23] => wooden [12] => black [109] => brass [111] => chrome [31] => silver [33] => white [76] => glass [38] => gold [21] => brown [47] => tan [46] => beige [138] => mirror [114] => steel [16] => multicolor [13] => leather [157] => mahogany [6] => red [166] => black and white [15] => acrylic )
```

but in the tag group "Attributes" I have 57 tags and above displayed not even half of them.

Any clue what is going on?

Thanks

Comment: Well, it looks like there is a glitch/bug in this add-on when trying to list all tags used for all entries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like issue is related to EE default settings not Tag addon

> I set the {exp:channel:entries} limit="" to 1000. When this parameter
>   was not used, which defaults at 100

That solves the problem.